# Polynomial representation of $\sum\limits_{n=m+1}^N \binom {n-1} m$

Tags: polynomials, summation, binomial-coefficients

**Background:** I am looking for a polynomial representation of
$$
\sum_{n=m+1}^N \binom {n-1} m \tag{1}
$$
where $m\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ is a positive integer $2,3,4,\ldots $ that is greater than or equal to $2$. I know how to write polynomials for small values of $m$ and am curious if the general case also produces a polynomial that can be written down by hand. Below I complete the analysis where $m=2$ and $m=3$.

**Case 1: m=2**. Equation $(1)$ becomes

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=3}^N \binom {n-1} 2 = \sum_{n=3}^N \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2} = \sum_{n=3}^N \frac{n^2-3n+2}{2}.
\end{equation}
Since
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=3}^N n^2 &= \sum_{n=1}^N n^2 - \sum_{n=1}^2 n^2 = \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}-5 = \frac{1}{6}\left(2N^3+3N^2+N-30\right), \\\\
3\sum_{n=3}^N n &= 3\sum_{n=1}^N n - 3\sum_{n=1}^2 n=\frac{3N(N+1)}{2} - 9 = \frac{3}{2}\left(N^2+N-6\right), \\\\
\sum_{n=3}^N 2  &= 2\sum_{n=1}^N 1 - 2\sum_{n=1}^2 1 = 2(N-2),
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=3}^N \binom {n-1} 2 &= \frac{1}{12}\left(2N^3+3N^2+N-30\right) - \frac{3}{4}\left(N^2+N-6\right) + (N-2) \notag\\\\&=
\boxed{\frac{N^3}{6} - \frac{N^2}{2} + \frac{N}{3}}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

**Case 2: m=3**. Equation $(1)$ becomes

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=4}^N \binom {n-1} 3 = \sum_{n=4}^N \frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{6} = \sum_{n=4}^N \frac{n^3-6n^2+11n-6}{6}.
\end{equation}
Because
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=4}^N n^3 &= \sum_{n=1}^N n^3 - \sum_{n=1}^3 n^3 = \frac{N^2(N+1)^2}{4} - 36 = \frac{1}{4}\left(N^4 + 2N^3 + N^2 - 144\right), \\\\
6\sum_{n=4}^N n^2 &= 6\sum_{n=1}^N n^2 - 6\sum_{n=1}^3 n^2 = N(N+1)(2N+1)-84 = 2N^3+3N^2+N-84, \\\\
11\sum_{n=4}^N n &= 11\sum_{n=1}^N n - 11\sum_{n=1}^3 n= \frac{11N(N+1)}{2} - 66 = \frac{11}{2}\left(N^2+N-12\right), \\\\
\sum_{n=4}^N 6  &= 6\sum_{n=1}^N 1 - 6\sum_{n=1}^3 1 = 6(N-3),
\end{align*}
we see that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=4}^N \binom {n-1} 3  &= \notag \frac{1}{24}\left(N^4 + 2N^3 + N^2 - 144\right) - \frac{1}{6}\left(2N^3+3N^2+N-84\right) \\\\
& + \frac{11}{12}\left(N^2+N-12\right) - (N-3) \notag \\\\&=
\boxed{\frac{N^4}{24} - \frac{N^3}{4} + \frac{11N^2}{24} - \frac{N}{4}}. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Next, I move onto the general case where $m$ is greater than $3$.

**Case 3: m=m**. Equation $(1)$ is
$$ 
\sum_{n=m+1}^N \binom {n-1} m = \sum_{n=m+1}^N\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-m)}{m!}=? \tag{4}.
$$

Through a computer algebraic system (such as [Mathematica](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%20%28n-1%29%20choose%20m%20from%20n%3Dm%2B1%20to%20n%3DN)), I found that
$$
\sum_{n=m+1}^N \binom {n-1} m  = \frac{\binom N m(N-m)}{m+1}=\boxed{\frac{(N-m)N!}{m!(N-m)!(m+1)}}\tag{5}.
$$

Equation $(5)$ follows from induction. For the inductive step, I assume

$$
\sum_{n=m+1}^N \binom {n-1} m  = \frac{\binom N m(N-m)}{m+1}.
$$

Adding $\binom{N}{m}$ to both sides to gives

$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{n=m+1}^{N+1} \binom {n-1} m &= \frac{\binom N m(N-m)}{m+1} + \binom{N}{m} \\&= 
\frac{(N+1)!}{(m+1)!(N-m)!} \\&=
\frac{(N+1)!(N+1-m)}{(m+1)!(N+1-m)!} \\&=
\frac{\binom {N+1} m (N+1-m)}{m+1}
\end{align*}$$

which validates $(5)$.

**Question:** Is $(5)$ the most general polynomial representation of the general case (similar to $(2)$ and $(3)$ when $m=2$ and $m=3$)? Would it be better to instead apply [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)?

Comment: Since you have the expression, have you tried proving it via induction?

Comment: Your identity (5) is called the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Comment: @ChrisLewis: Yes, induction works for verifying $(5)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you found in (5) is the [Hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity), yours can be written more simply as
$$
\sum_{n=m+1}^N \dbinom {n-1} m=\binom{N}{m+1}.
$$
If you wanted it as a polynomial in $N$, i.e. expressing its coefficients, then again yes [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) are the answer. By definition $(x)_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}s(n,k)x^k$ and so
$$
\sum_{n=m+1}^N \dbinom {n-1} m=\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\frac{s(m+1,k)}{(m+1)!}N^k.
$$

Comment: The expression simplifies to 

$$
 \binom M {m+1}= \frac{N(N-1)\cdots(N-m)}{(m+1)!}.
$$
Do you need the $\color{blue}{\text{additional summation term}}$ in the falling factorial polynomial?

$$\sum_{n=m+1}^N \dbinom {n-1} m=\sum_{k=0}^{\color{blue}{m+1}}\frac{s(m+1,k)}{(m+1)!}N^k$$

This may be because the falling factoral polynomial has $(m+1)$ factors

$$N_{(m+1)} = N(N-1)\cdots(N-m).$$

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "need", this is just rewritten definition of Stirling numbers, note that $\binom{N}{m+1}=\frac{(N)_{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$. Also I would not necessarily call $\frac{N(N-1)\cdots(N-m)}{(m+1)!}$ simpler than $\binom N {m+1}$.